# Can I replace a 3A plug on a light fixture (that comes with 3A cable) with a 5A plug?

Tags: electrical

Can I replace a 3A plug on a light fixture (that comes with 3A cable) with a 5A plug?

The 1st problem I encountered is that the cable has 2 power lines rather than 3 which connect to the 5A plug.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Hi, can you provide some details about your location?

Answer (score 6):

From the mention of 3A and 5A plugs, I'm guessing that you're in the UK (or a country that uses the same style plugs).

The only difference between a 3A and a 5A plug is the fuse, and the [fuses in a UK plug are interchangeable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_1363#Fuses), so to convert the 5A plug to a 3A plug, just remove the old 5A fuse and install a new 3A fuse.

Your fixture doesn't have an earth lead, meaning that it's [double insulated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II).  Connect the two wires on your light fixture to the terminals marked 2 and 4 in this diagram:

[image]

(Image courtesy of the Wikipedia article on [UK plugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS_1363))

Answer (score 0):

No, i changed the 3a fuse on ipad charger 2 times, because it would stop working again and again, i used a 5a fuse and it just blew up, thankfully the charger didn’t take on any damage only the outer plug got damaged, i replaced it and found out the problem was in the wall socket not the charger

Comment: If the problem is the socket, then changing the plug makes no difference.  You can change the plug without a problem.